# UWP How to allow a child element to be drawn outside the bounds of a RelativePanel

Tags: c#, uwp, clipping, relativepanel

I have a RelativePanel `Panel1` whose Size is (300,300).

I have a child RelativePanel `ChildPanel` inside `Panel1` which I want to move, by setting its `Margin`.

When I move outside the boundaries of `Panel1` (e.g. setting `ChildPanel.Margin.Left = 400`), `ChildPanel` disappears.

How can I let `ChildPanel` be drawn even if it is outside the boundaries of `Panel1`?

Comment: maybe use a negative margin like Margin="-205,0,0,0"

Comment: If I set a margin for the child that is outside the size of the parent, the child is not visible.

Comment: How did you move the child panel outside the parent panel?

Comment: I use Margin property, see my updated question

Answer (score 1):

The RelativePanel doesn't support this behavior when child elements are outside the boundaries. You should make a custom control to achieve this. This control looks a Floating Panel Control. Please check this sample: https://github.com/XamlBrewer/UWP-Floating-Content-Sample

Comment: The Floating Panel Control seems promising, but unfortunately is based on a Canvas, and I cannot use Canvas in my project :( Do you have any other solution?

Comment: @CristianoGhersi I do not know other ways. If you just want to use the RelativePanel to achieve your target, I think it's impossible.

Answer (score 0):

As I learned directly from Microsoft guys, this is impossible, but it is possible to add instead the child to another Panel higher in the visual tree!

This requires to be a little bit more careful in managing the dynamic appeareance / disappearance of the child, but is good enough for this use case.